# How to initialize a struct based on given address?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm working on C language. 
I have a pointer and I wanna create a new struct beginning with the address. Here is my way to do it and I can pass the compile but when I run it, it gets bus error and segment error.

```
struct node{
    int value;
    int value2
    struct node *next;
}

int main(){
    struct node a = {0, 0, NULL};
    void *p = (void*)(&a + 1);
    struct node *ptr = (struct node *)(p);
    //These two statements below cause the problem.
    (*ptr).value = 100;
    (*ptr).next = NULL;
}
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Of course we'd have to have the definition of `some_method_to_get_address` because that is where the fault is. (BTW, `(*ptr).value)` is commonly written as `ptr->value`).

Comment: I guess you're using an embedded system that has a register set at a given address?  Apart from what @AnttiHaapala said, your (struct node) should also be (struct node *), and you might want to cast to addr_t in-between to ensure that the "integer" you get back as an address is the right size for an address pointer.

Comment: @c.fogelklou a linked list usually wouldn't be at a set address.

Comment: @c.fogelklou I have correct the (struct node *). It is a typo.

Comment: you know you can't just poke around in random memory and hope stuff's gonna be right, um? If you want a list of consecutively-allocated objects, that's called an **array.**

Comment: @AATRSong you're probably getting the error since you're accessing a misaligned address, or a value that isn't even on the stack..  Why are you adding 1 to 'a' - that is one past the end of "a".  sizeof(int) is 4 and sizeof(struct node) is 8.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I change the some_method... to some variable. Hope you can solve it.

Comment: Well, simply put, this is undefined behaviour in C. You cannot just cast some random number into a pointer, then poke some stuff into it. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @c.fogelklou thanks for your suggestion. I have pay attention to the misaligned address. In my code, the struct has two unsigned int variable and a pointer, which is 16.

Comment: @AATRSong, "a" is only 4 bytes in your comment, so these are the only valid bytes on your stack.  You are casting it's address to a struct which is at least 8 bytes according to your code, and then modifying ALL of it, which of course is going to cause issues, since ALL if it includes the bytes that aren't defined on the stack.  Why not change "int a" to "struct node a"? (edit: of course I'm assuming 32-bits.  YMMV if 16/64 bit)

Comment: @c.fogelklou that'd actually overwrite the function return address or base pointer or such on x86; it is also +1, so on x86 all of it would point outside the allocated object.

Comment: In any case, this is most probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to solve Y and you think it'd be solvable via X, but you run into problems. However the X is not even a correct step to solve Y.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala actually I'm not so sure about that.  he's probably overwriting the contents of "void *p" which is also on the stack, or "struct node *ptr" which is also on the stack, but then he dereferences these corrupted pointers, so there is no way to NOT crash this code.  It's destined to burn in some way.

Comment: @c.fogelklou well yeah, either way it burns.

Comment: @c.fogelklou As you said, I have changing it but still error

Comment: Do this: (no need for fancy address tricks)  
    struct node a = {0, 0, NULL};
    struct node *ptr = &a;
    ptr->value = 100;
    ptr->next = NULL; or simply a.value = 100; a.next = NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming you can only use statically defined memory and want a linked list:

```
struct node{
    int value;
    int value2
    struct node *next;
};

#define LEN 10
static struct node arr[LEN] = {0};

int main(){
    // Initialize the array of nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
       struct node * const ptr = &a[i];
       ptr->value = 100;
       ptr->next = (i == (LEN-1)) ? NULL : &a[i+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `p` points to a memory location that passes the address of `a` which is an integer, it is undefined behavior to access it anyway.

What you want is allocating the memory instead, e.g.:

```
struct node *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);

ptr->value = 100;
ptr->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Good comment, I saw this too but didn't want to make an "answer" of this since the code he posted wouldn't even compile and thusly could never produce a bus error - since it wouldn't even run.

Comment: I have correct it. It's a typo

Comment: @AATRSong `*(&a+1)` still UB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Really good solution. But I cannot use malloc() function since I'm trying to implement the same thing on a fixed size of memory

Comment: @AATRSong What's the purpose of that? If you really cannot use `malloc`, you can do `struct node a[2]; void *p = a + 1;` The point is the pointer must refer to a memory that has *defined* storage.

Comment: The purpose is that there is some space between two struct. The size of space depends. So I have new a struct after the given size of space.